# CMake error in installing Ray on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ray, flow-project, rllib

I cloned the Ray repository from Github (https://github.com/flow-project/ray.git) and am trying to install it on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the instructions provided on https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html, but am encountering an error during the installation process.
How to resolve the build error that occurs when installing Ray RLlib in Flow traffic simulator? I followed the instructions on the Flow documentation website to install SUMO, and then ran the following commands to install Ray:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/flow-project/ray.git
cd ray/python/
python setup.py develop
```

However, I received the following build error for the last command:

```
...
CMake Error: Unknown argument -O3
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options.
CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'external/arrow/src/arrow_ep-stamp/arrow_ep-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [external/arrow/src/arrow_ep-stamp/arrow_ep-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:411: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failedmake: *** [all] Error 2
..
```

In addition to installing Ray, I followed the installation instructions on the official Ray GitHub repository and ran the following commands to ensure their system was properly set up:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y cmake pkg-config build-essential autoconf curl libtool unzip flex bison psmisc python
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install cython==0.29.0
```

I am using 'CMake' version 3.25.2 and 'setuptools' version 58.1.0. Do I need to install any other dependencies before running 'python setup.py develop'? Or is there anything else I need to do to fix the error? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"pip install ray==0.8.0" resolved the issue I was facing.